# Is it possible to generate the space separated header row using data factory copy activity?

Tags: azure-data-factory

[image: reference image]

I am using azure sql as source dataset and delimited file as sink dataset in the copy activity.

I tried copy activity but First row as header gives comma separated headers.

Is there way to change the header output style ?
Please note spacing is unequal (h3...h4)

Comment: Do you want only header to be space separated ?

Comment: @Aswin, No,The headers are unequally spaced and data would follow the same. It's similar to fixed width file structure.

Comment: In sink dataset, try editing the column delimiter and give a space as value. Refer this [image](https://i.imgur.com/cHOcxBm.png).

Comment: @Aswin, Could you show me your output file?

Comment: Check if this is your requirement. [Output](https://i.imgur.com/jobeAG1.png)

Comment: Thanks @Aswin, But this would always keep equal spacing between headers as well the data. If you see the reference image, h3,h4 and h5,h6 has different spacing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249102/discussion-between-aswin-and-ashwin-mohan).

Answer (score 1):

In this repro, I tried to give

- 1 space between 1st and 2nd column,
- 2 spaces between 2nd and 3rd column,
- 3 spaces between 3rd and 4th column.
  Also, I tried to give same column name for column2 and column3. The approach is as follows.

1. Data is copied from Azure SQL database to datalake in comma delimitted format as a staging file.
   [image: img]
2. This staging file is taken as a source in Dataflow activity.
   [image: img]
3. In source dataset, first row as header is not checked.

[image]

**Data preview of Source transformation:**
[image]

3. Derived column transformation is added to change the column name of column2 and column3.
   In this case, date_col of column1 is header data. Thus when column1 is 'date_col' replace column2 and column3 data with same column name.

column_2 = `iif(Column_1=='date_col','ECIX',Column_2)`;
column_3 = `iif(Column_1=='date_col','ECIX',Column_3)`;

[image]

4. Again derived column transformation is added to concat all the columns with spaces. Column name is given as **concat** . Value for this column is
   `concat(Column_1,' ',Column_2,'  ',Column_3,'   ',Column_4)`
   [image]
   [image]
5. Select transformation is added and only **concat** column is selected here. [image]
6. In sink, new delimited file is added as a sink dataset. And in sink dataset also , first row as header is not checked.
   [image: gif5]

**Output file screenshot**
After pipeline is run, the target file looks like this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the source as azure sql itself in the dataflow, I created a  single derived column 'OUTDC' and added all the columns from the source like this:

```
(h1)+' '+(h2)+'      '+(h3)
```

Then fed the OUTDC to a delimited sink and kept the **Headers** option as single string like this:

```
['h1    h2          h2']
```